# VS2015 how to get a breakpoint in an additional project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I am using visual studio 2015 to develop Program A.

It makes use of a new general hardware Library B which is also in development, but in a different project.

.

In visual studio while i have opened A, I've added existing project B. So project A, has B as a .dll reference and can make use of compiled B code.
B provides its own typical class, with its own defined namespace etc.

Sometimes I need to fix or test new things in library B.
So that A can use a new or updated function written in B.
To use use a new function I do a batch compile of A and B. If the new function compiles OK and works, then so far so good no problems.

But Sometimes things are not OK and don't work as supposed, and I need to check what happens inside B when running aplication A. However if I set a breakpoint in the B project, nothing happens ???.

How can I set a breakpoint in B, wile I am testing A.

PS, I have "just my code" disabled.

Comment: did you check if pdb files of project B are getting copied in Project A bin?

Comment: When debugging, you can open the Modules window under `Debug->Windows->Modules`. There you can verify that symbols for B.dll are loaded, and if not, load them (the pdb file that @Viru mentioned). After that, any breakpoint in a source file of B.dll should be triggered properly. Be sure to check that there is no warning in the breakpoint glyph.

Comment: Ehm i dont have a Modules under the DEbug\windows\ menu ?

Comment: You will need to be actively debugging to se the modules window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like no symbols loaded for the module in project B. To ensure symbols are loaded, be sure you have the correct pdb for the module and add the path to that pdb to your symbols path under Debug->Settings->Symbol settings. Also, under the same menu you can either select "load all symbols" or"load only select" and add the name of the module to the list of modules.

Comment: Well i am using vs2015, i think things are handled slightly different.
Here i have under the menu Debug \Options

Options opens a panel with debugging settings i can expand General (this is where enable just my code stands)
But there is a sub under debugging about symbols

In there i see it uses the MS symbol servers
It caches symbols under a local temp.
And "Automatically load symbols for all modules unless excluded is"  enabled.  (nothing excluded)

Comment: If that's the case, then symbols *should* load automatically assuming the path to the pdb for your module is in the symbol search path. If they don't, it is most likely because the pdb you are using does not match the binary.

Comment: hmm the code solutions..not sure how to call it, well the source code is not in the same folder. as A is a probram that uses the B.dll, but future programs are suposed to use B to its a general dll ,so B lives in another file folder. Is that where VS2015 looses track of it, and if thats the case how do i tell VS2015 to look there ?.

Comment: Ok well i added an entry under the default "Microsoft Symbol Servers" entry, there i wrote down the pdb file location of the release version of the B .dll and now it works. Strange that vs2015 didnt do that automatically.